# Cursor: pointer on hover or always?

Tags: css, sass

I was aking my self this question: What are the differences, if there are, about having the property `cursor: pointer;` always or just in the `:hover` ?

Take this snippet:

```css
.test{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">Hover me
```

and this other snippet:

```css
.hoverme:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="hoverme">Hover me</span>
```

both do the same thing: setting up the cursor icon. But is it really necessary to put this property (the cursor's property) in the `hover`?

I mean, logically has more sense to put it in the `hover`, but I don't get it.

Obviously if I have to change the background on hover this example answer itself. But what about my question?

Comment: I'd say it just make more sense semantically to use it on hover. The same way that `<b>` and `<strong>` produce the same visual result, but are quite different in meaning. Btw, I was asking myself this very question. Right now I am reading about it and trying to find some definitive answer/guide. Until then, I will always use it on hover.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac thank you for your answer. I tried to search on google but sadly I didn't find anything relevant about that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that makes a difference would be the small performance hit of having an extra rule.. but unless you have 1000 different classes, each with a :hover that ONLY has cursor. I don't see performance being an issue. So, semantically it makes sense to use it on :hover and also... your :hover PROBABLY has other stuff too. Sadly I don't have enough reference or evidence to make this an actual answer. But I guess TL:DR "Performance.. Maybe?"

Comment: I would say that `:hover` is already part of cursor behaviour so you don’t need to specify it in CSS for cursor behaviour. Only use `:hover` for styles that need to change on the element itself, when the cursor is over it.

Comment: I have found this answer on Quora. (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-someclass-cursor-pointer-and-someclass-hover-cursor-pointer-while-both-effects-are-the-same/answer/Marty-Naselli). Even it has some effect on performance, it's definitely insignificant. I couldn't find anything other than "pereference/opinion based" info anywhere online. Good question, tho.

Comment: I get a slight visual difference between the two in my browser (Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 on Mac OSX 10.13.2). For the snippet that applies the style on hover, the cursor is the same that it would be on normal text for just a moment before changing. I don't have that effect on the first snippet.

Comment: @ChristopherBradshaw that's true. I also noticed that

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry the difference is clear when using custom cursor (check the duplicate)

Comment: I don't want to write an answer because I'm not confident, but I remember a few years when I put `cursor: pointer` on the `:hover`, there would be times when it wouldn't register immediately,,, like it'd take a **split second** longer than I expected. I don't know if I was lagging that day but I've put my `cursor: pointer` on the base element since then. If this is true, I think the reasoning is simply by putting `cursor: pointer` on `:hover` the browser has to check if the cursor is hovering, and then check if it's hovering again, before updating the cursor (as opposed to just checking once).

Answer (score -4):

Visually, there are no differences. However, there are some cases that make `cursor: pointer;` very useful. The `cursor: pointer;` is useful in cases, for a better user experience, you need it to change to a pointer. For example: if you have a `button` element in your HTML and you hover over it, your cursor will not change by default. But if you add the `cursor: pointer;` to that element in your CSS along with the `:hover`, it can improve user experience by encouraging interaction with the element.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but It's kinda off-topic. I know that the pointer is more user-friendly, I was just wondering if there are some importan differences having this property setted only on hover or always

Comment: I think that really depends on what element you're working with. You'll get the same effect with either option.

Comment: Infact, having some other properties on hover (IE: background color different) is something different

Comment: @NicholasThurston I don't think you understood the question.